# jScrollPane Scroll dissapears after jPanel resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, netbeans-7

I'm currently writing a Java GUI application using NetbeansIDE 7.4 and have encountered the following problem:

I have a jPannel enclosed in a jScrollPane of initial dimension 300,160
Every time i click on a jButton at runtime, I resize the jPannel as follows:

```
jPanel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, (count + 3) * 30));
jPanel3.repaint();
```

if the count variable is larger than 3, the Vertical Scrollbar adapts to the jPannel every time I resize it.

But if count is less than 3, the vertical scrollbar dissapears, and when I resize the jPannel again ( lets say, count = 10), the Scrollbar doesn't show up anymore.

Is this normal? How can i fix it?

Comment: If this were my problem and I were seeking help here, I'd take a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me. Might help you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this normal? How can i fix it?

Don't know if that is normal or not, but that is not the proper way to resize the panel. A Swing component is responsible to determining its size, not your application code. This is done by creating a setter method when you want to change a property of your component.

If you want to dynamically change the size of the panel then you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel. Something like:

```
@Override
public Dimentsion getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension( new Dimension(300, (getCount() + 3) * 30) );
}
```

Then in you class you should create a setter (and getter) method for your count:

```
public void setCount(int count)
{
    this.count = count;
    revalidate()
    repaint();
}
```

Now the revalidate will cause the preferred size to be recalculated and the scroll pane will then use the new preferred size.